# Quarkus rest client ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl in native mode

Tags: java, maven, quarkus, classnotfoundexception, quarkus-native

I've got a Quarkus project with multiple modules.

```
└── Parent module
        └── Common module
        └── child module
        └── some module
```

In the common module I've added the following dependencies (following this guide https://quarkus.io/guides/rest-client).

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
    <artifactId>quarkus-rest-client</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
    <artifactId>quarkus-rest-client-jackson</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

The child module has the common module as a dependency.

And the code snippets I'm using inside the child module.

```
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@ApplicationScoped
@RegisterRestClient(configKey = "URL")
@RegisterClientHeaders(AuthorizationHeaderFactory.class)
public interface MyRestClient {

    @POST
    @Path("/{id}")
    FooResponse<FooResponseData> makeFooPayout(@PathParam("id") String accountId,
                                            FooRequest<FooData> requestData);
    }
}
```

And calling it from another ApplicationScoped class:

```
    FooResponse<FooResponseData> fooResponse = myRestClient.makeFooPayout(
            payoutDTO.id(),
            fooRequest
    );
```

When running the the application in native mode it throws the `ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl`.

I stumbled across this one (https://quarkus.io/guides/logging#logging-adapters) thinking it would solve the issue for me.

I followed the guide by trying to exclude the logging from the rest-client dependencies in the parent module.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
        <artifactId>quarkus-rest-client</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
        <artifactId>quarkus-rest-client-jackson</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

And added one of the adapters as suggested in the documentation:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-logging-jboss-logging</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Why is this not solving the issue? Have I missed something? Am I supposed to exclude the logging dependency inside of the child pom.xml?

Answer (score 0):

This has now been solved, following this guide https://quarkus.io/guides/logging#logging-adapters.

In the common module inside the pom I added this, to ALL dependencies (uncertain if all of them really need to exclude `commons-logging`).

```
   <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
```

And also added one of the JBoss Logging adapters as suggested in Quarkus documentation.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-logging-jboss-logging</artifactId>
</dependency>
```